# PSDMatrix completion

Tags: matrix

How can I write a code which gets as an input a symmetric square matrix X with some (symmetric pairs of) entries marked, and outputs whether there is an assignment of values to the marked entries such that the resulting matrix is positive semi-definite?

Comment: It's very discouraging to see questions that ask for a task but show little effort themselves. If you expect to inspire anybody to **volunteer their time to look at your problem**, then start by doing your part. Get the *Informed* badge by taking and understanding the [tour]. Give context, explain what is the goal, show your efforts to find a solution yourself. To add new information [edit] your question, use the *comments* section just for comments. Share your code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX).

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Kindly include Mathematica code (in copy-paste-able form) that you have tried out so far and indicate where you are having difficulty. Thanks.